# using powershell, how do I check if a particular remote file share is available?

Tags: networking, powershell, network-shares

My Powershell script assumes that the user running the script has access to a particular remote share on a fileserver.   If they don't, I want to prompt the user to "map a network drive" first prior to running the script.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*<sub>Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but I am assuming here that we are checking here if user has required share mapped, not if user has access to required share.</sub>*

---

I realize that this is not exactly answering your question but I would suggest a different approach.

You could try mapping the share in your script using New-PsDrive cmdlet and if needed prompting user for credential with `Get-Credential`

```
New-PSDrive -Name TestName -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\fileshare.local\share -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

At the end of your script detach from it using `Remove-PsDrive` cmdlet.

*Mapped Share will only be visible in the script context (won't appear in Windows Explorer).*

---

Finally, you could also use this method to check if share is mapped

```
    If(Get-PSDrive | Where-Object DisplayRoot -EQ '\\fileshare.local\share'){ "Mappped" } else { "Nope" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's PowerShell code that will do what you're looking for.

```
$connected = $false
try {
  if ((get-item \\mycomp1\myshare).Name -eq "myshare") { $connected = $true }
} catch {
}
if (-not($connected)) {
  echo "Please map network drive to \\mycomp1\myshare using your domain credentials, and try again"
  exit
}
```